# How to read a file into Vector of Doubles?

Tags: file, haskell

I have a name of a file (as a string), and that file contains certain amount (1000000, for example) double-precision floating-point values (stored as binary, 8 bytes for each, obviously).

What would be the best way to read those doubles into a vector?

Comment: Are you using the `binary` package from Hackage?

Comment: @jozefg - Yes, currently I'm trying to put together something using that package.

Comment: @Rogach Take a look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-binary-instances

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov - I already did. We had a very funny discussion at #haskell irc, and finally figured out the solution. Unless somebody posts a better answer, I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it in the end:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VM
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Get
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import Unsafe.Coerce

readDoubles :: Int -> FilePath -> IO (V.Vector Double)
readDoubles n f = BS.readFile f >>= return . runGet (getVector n)

getVector :: Int -> Get (V.Vector Double)
{-# INLINE getVector #-}
getVector n = do
    mv <- liftGet $ VM.new n
    let fill i
            | i < n = do
                x <- fmap unsafeCoerce getWord64be
                (unsafePerformIO $ VM.unsafeWrite mv i x) `seq` return ()
                fill (i+1)
            | otherwise = return ()
    fill 0
    liftGet $ V.unsafeFreeze mv

liftGet :: IO b -> Get b
liftGet = return . unsafePerformIO
```

Comment: Is all the unsafe stuff really necessary here? I'd expect a simple `V.replicateM n get` to do the job.

Comment: @hammar - If I define `getVector` as `V.replicateM n get`, I get an error `too few bytes. Failed reading at byte position 8000001` when trying to read the file. That's due to some bug in `Get` instance for `Double`. To avoid that, I used that unsafe coerce (also, simply coercing is 2 times faster than any other approach) - but still, if I define `getVector` as `V.replicateM n (fmap unsafeCoerce getWord64be)`, I get stack overflow.